# Request' object has no attribute 'get': Django Views &. Serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, error-handling

I am working on a Dajngo DRF app serving as the API for my app.

I am really struggling to debug this error: Request object has no attribute 'get'.

The error pops up after I update my organisation. The error is being caught as an exception, so I am fairly certain it is coming from the patch method of my OrganisationDetail view. Here is the view below:

```
class OrganisationDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete an organisation.
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsInOrg)
    queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganisationSerializer
    logger.info("Init log from organisation view")

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Organisation.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Organisation.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status=404)

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        organisation = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = OrganisationSerializer(organisation)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            organisation = self.get_object(pk)
            data = copy.deepcopy(request.data)
            member_to_remove = request.data.get(
                'user_to_remove', 'no_user_to_remove')
            if member_to_remove != 'no_user_to_remove':
                data['member_to_remove'] = member_to_remove
            if "name" not in data:
                data["name"] = organisation.name
            if "description" not in data:
                data["description"] = organisation.description

            serializer = OrganisationSerializer(
                organisation, data=data, context=request, partial=True)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                logger.info(f"PATCH SUCCESSFUL: {serializer.data}")
                return Response(serializer.data)
            logger.warning(f"PATCH Failed: {serializer.errors}")
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"PATCH Failed with exception: {e}")
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
```

I am also going to include my serializer in the hope that this helps:

```
class OrganisationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    owner = serializers.CharField()
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    new_member = MemberSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Organisation
        fields = [
            'id',
            'owner',
            'name',
            'description',
            'members'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Organisation` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        # an organisation needs the owner to exist
        # so first we create the owner as an
        # inactive user and send them an activation email
        user = create_user_for_organisation(
            validated_data['owner'],
            "ADMIN"
        )
        user.save(update_fields=["is_active"])
        org_data = {
            "owner": user,
            "name": validated_data['name'],
            "description": validated_data['description']
        }
        try:
            org = Organisation.objects.create(**org_data)
            org.members.set([user])
            org.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed to create Organisation', e)

        send_user_activation_email(user, self.context['request'])
        send_owner_confirmation_email(user, self.context['request'])

        return org

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
            owner = User.objects.get(
                email=validated_data.get('owner', instance.owner.email))
            instance.owner = owner
            new_member_details = validated_data.get('new_member')
            if new_member_details != None:
                new_member = create_user_for_organisation(
                    new_member_details['email'], new_member_details['role'])
                instance.members.add(new_member)
                send_user_activation_email(new_member, self.context)
            member_to_remove_id = QueryDict.get(
                self.initial_data, key='user_to_remove')
            if member_to_remove_id != None:
                try:
                    content_lock = ContentLock.objects.get(
                        user_id=member_to_remove_id)
                    content_lock.delete()
                except:
                    pass
                user_to_remove = User.objects.get(id=member_to_remove_id)
                instance.members.remove(user_to_remove)
            instance.save()
            return instance
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(
                f"Serializer Failed to update organisation with exception: {e}")
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            user = self.context['request'].user
        except Exception:
            user = self.context.user
        except Exception:
            user = self.context
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User not found.")
        if not Organisation.objects.has_create_permission(user):
            if not Organisation.objects.has_update_permissions(user, self.instance.owner.email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "User not allowed to create or update organisation.")
        cleandata = data
        if 'members' in self.initial_data:
            if isinstance(self.initial_data['members'], list):
                cleandata['members'] = self.initial_data['members']
            else:
                cleandata['members'] = []
                cleandata['members'].append(self.initial_data["members"])

        return cleandata
```

The error occurs after I add a user to the organisation (patch method in view, update in serializer). The user is created by updating the organisation.

There are two very strange things about this error:

1. The error never shows up on my localhost, and only occurs when I deploy to staging on GCP.
2. The user is still created, but patch request returns with a 500 response.

I unfortunately have not got my logging to propegate to GCP using stackdriver, an issue for another post. The only indication of error I can find is the one that is logged by the api client in the front end which reads: Request' object has no attribute 'get'

I am at a loss and any help is appreciated. thanks

I have tried to remove all .gets in the patch method of the view, and use some (fairly ugly) try excepts to handle unfound values in the dict. Even after removing all the dict.get() methods I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you post your traceback? Also, is the google-cloud-platform tag necessary? This issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with cloud deployment.

Comment: Can you try to isolate the error even further? Perhaps deploy just the patch method alone, with the most barebones patching logic, and see if it still throws the error?

Comment: @PawelKam thank you. I have edited the flag. It snuck in there because I have also been struggling to get my logging to work on GCP but I opened another thread for that here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340815/sending-logs-to-gcp-from-django-drf-application

The issue is only when it’s deployed so I don’t have much more of a trace back then the one I put in the title of this thread I hitch comes from the browser console of my client

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple. When initialising the serializer to a variable, the request object needs to be passed in correctly, as demonstrated below. The request object needs to have an explicit key and the value of data should come straight from the request:

```
serializer = OrganisationSerializer(
                organisation, data=request.data, context={'request': request}, partial=True)
```